# My godaddy linux host is kinda blocking my htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting

I have a linux shared hosting account with GoDaddy, and I've tried the following to hide my html extension from my website:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

It didn't work, so I contacted support, they said it was because of the htaccess file and that the hosting wasn't blocking the htaccess file, so I tried this:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Also, I tried adding DirectoryIndex custom.html to have a unique index file name, but it didn't work, so is there any other way to do it? I just want to hide html file extensions. I also tried adding DirectoryIndex custom.html to have a unique index file name, but it didn't work. Only index.html is acceptable.

Comment: The code you posted does not "hide" anything. It assumes you are already linking to the URL _without_ an extension (as you should be). Is that the case?

Comment: İf its wrong please let me know which code will help me hide my HTML extension

Comment: The code above is not "wrong" as such. But your perception of what that code does might be. What is the format of the URL(s) you are linking to? You don't use `.htaccess` to actually "hide" the file extension on the URL. You hide the extension by physically removing the file extension on the URLs you are linking to in your HTML source. You can remove the file extension in `.htaccess` later (for SEO) if you are changing an existing URL structure that used file extensions - but this is secondary and not required to make your site work.

Comment: However, "I also tried adding `DirectoryIndex custom.html` to have a unique index file name, but it didn't work" - this is very different. In what way didn't this work? Did you get an error? Unexpected response? How are you calling this and expecting the `DirectoryIndex` to be served? It's technically possible the host has blocked this, but that would seem very unlikely.

Comment: @MrWhite look my only request is instead of showing the domain www.domain.com/gallery.html to be www.domain.com/gallery and i did removed the html extensions inside my html pages so now if i visit the pages i am geting page error !!!

Comment: @MrWhite DirectoryIndex custom.html did not work i got error 500 i guess its not allowed to change that !!!

Comment: In that case, the directives should work as is. Have you tried typing some nonsense at the top of the `.htaccess` file - do you get an error (EDIT: This should if your `DirectoryIndex` directive is)? Have you tried a direct one-to-one rewrite, eg. `RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.html [L]` ?

Comment: Have you got access to the server's error log? This would have the details of the 500 error and tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @MrWhite i am not that exprert i got the code from google so i have no idea playing around with the htaccess sorry :/ but i am going crazy cause i get it from a youtube channel and all comments are positive and still cant figure it out how to make it work :P

Comment: You have `Options +MultiViews` in your second example. That alone _should_ allow you to have extensionless URLs. (This will effectively override the mod_rewrite directives that are trying to do the same thing.) If this isn't working then something else is going on. Does your host use persistent server-side caching?! Presumably you have ensured that any client-side caches (and proxies) are cleared?

Comment: @MrWhite  [Fri Feb 18 10:15:06.542621 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 144758:tid 139951517546240] [client 192.185.83.56:36778] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/jugj80f9fcxh/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,index.shtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html,welcome.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: That error does not relate to the 500 error you mentioned earlier. That would be the 403 that results when a directory index document is not found.

Comment: @MrWhite sorry i told you i am not that expert in this fieled Options +MultiViews i did try it didnt work i wil try it again but i dont think its gonna work

Comment: @MrWhite thanks a lot man really apreciate you help but i dont think its gonna work neither to have  custom.html as index directory neither to be able to hide the html extension :/

Comment: Seems to be something odd going on. It is very unusual for a shared host to cripple `.htaccess` in this way. Have you tried just a single rule as mentioned above. ie. `RewriteEngine On` / `RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.html [L]`? And then request `/gallery`.

Comment: @MrWhite so the code will look like :   Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]                                                            
RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.html [L]

Comment: I would recommend just trying the code in my comment above first.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sabahoo$ sabahoo.html [L] didnt work :/

Comment: To clarify, the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root?

Comment: @MrWhite yes inside public.html folder

Comment: `RewriteRule ^sabahoo$ sabahoo.html [L]` - Try removing the `^` at the start of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. ie. `RewriteRule sabahoo$ sabahoo.html [L]`. To clarify, you have no other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite Finally the problem solved man haha it was from the server the support did somthing with permision and config thanks a lot man really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1):

So basically the problem was from the server and the support solve it so now my htaccess is as the following :

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Glad the webhost resolved the issue eventually! However, the two rules above are in the wrong order and you should _disable_ MultiViews (not enable it) here. Any HTTP (as opposed to HTTPS) request that is rewritten to `.html` (by MultiViews/mod_negotiation _or_ mod_rewrite) will expose the `.html` file extension. If MultiViews is enabled then your first rule is not really doing anything (MultiViews takes priority).